# Continuity dot product

Tags: general-topology

let $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ fixed, let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ how do i prove, using topological staff (specifically, natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and product topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that the map

$f_{\vec{u}}(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} u_i x_i$ is continuous?

I basically tried to solve a system of inequality, but i don't know if it is the best way...

(PS. no metric stuff here)

Comment: Show that your map is differentiable. or Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171487/inner-product-is-jointly-continuous). Why *no metric stuf* if you are in $\Bbb R^n$ with product topology?

Comment: Just because i want to make practice with the topological definition of continuity, no the metric one which involves norm, distance concept etc.

Comment: @Lukkio What is your approach to define differentiability in absence of a norm?

Comment: Indeed i don't want to use such concept...

Comment: For $n=1$ (i.e. $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$) you can prove it using the monotonicity of $f(x)=ux$. From that I think it directly follows for the case of general $n$ that if only one of the $u_i$ is non-zero, the function is continuous (because the preimage is the preimage of the corresponding one-coordinate function times $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ for the other coordinates). If you then prove that the sum of continuous functions is again continuous, you are ready.

Comment: So you suggest to exploit function composition (which is good to for what i want to do)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for $x,y \in \mathbf R^n$, we have 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|} 
  \abs{f_u(x) - f_u(y)} \le \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm u \cdot \norm{x-y} $$

---

Addendum (less norms): Let $U$ be open in $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R$, we will show that $f_u^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\R^n$. To do so, let $x \in f_u^{-1}[U]$, i. e., $f_u(x) \in U$. We have to find open sets $U_i \subseteq \R$ such that $x \in \prod_i U_i \subseteq f_u^{-1}[U]$. As $U$ is open, there is some Interval $(a,b)$ such that $f_u(x) \in (a,b) \subseteq U$. Now use Cauchy-Schwarz to give the $U_i$'s.

Comment: This proves that in fact $\;f_u\;$ is uniformly continuous. +1

Comment: You're involving here the norm concept... which isn't what i'm looking for...

Comment: Somewhere you'll have to use that $\mathbf R$'s topology is given by the absolute value or the order ...

Comment: What do you mean? What i want to proove is that for given $x$ and interval $]a,b[$ the preimage is a set $X = \prod ]a_i,b_i[$. Can i prove such stuff without using metric concept? (the interval $]a,b[$ contains $f(x)$).

Comment: @Lukkio Haven't you proved the Euclidean topology **is** the one obtained with the Euclidean Norm?

Comment: Indeed you're speaking of Euclidean... i mean my hypothesis are the topology i'm considering in $\mathbb{R}$ is the order topology, and what i'm considering in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology , induced by the order topology. (i.e. the one which the basis is product of basis element of $\mathbb{R}$ with the open interval topology$

Comment: I know the difference between the topology and a base, what i was trying to do is to express what i'm looking for. Basically what i'm trying to do... is to express the solution set of the inequality $a < f_{\vec{u}}(\vec{x}) < b$ as interection finite or arbitrary union of open of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which the product topology derived from the order topology defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here is an idea (which i think works for $n = 2$, but i guess i could do something similar in general). So... the idea is take a solution x for the $a < f_{\vec{u}}(\vec{x}) < b$ and prove $\vec{x} \in \textbf{Int S}$ (Interior set, which is union of the open set belonging to the solution set), in that case what i have should be $\textbf{Int S} \subset S \subset \textbf{Int S}$ so the solution set can be expressed as arbitrary union of open set, which is open. Does make it sense?