# Double Limit of operators converges weakly, does single limit converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, nets, strong-convergence

I am working on a problem from Reed and Simon, which states:

Suppose $\{A_\alpha\}$ and $\{B_\alpha\}$, $\alpha \in I$, are nets.  Let $A_\alpha^* \to A^*$ and $B_\alpha \to B$ in the Strong Operator Topology.  Prove that $A_\alpha B_\alpha \to AB$ in the Weak Operator Topology.

Note that these operators are defined on a Hilbert space.

Clearly, SOT convergence implies WOT convergence, so we most certainly have that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_\beta \lim_\alpha \langle A_\alpha(B_\beta x), y \rangle = \langle A(Bx), y \rangle = \lim_\alpha \lim_\beta \langle A_\alpha(B_\beta x), y \rangle.
\end{align*}

The problem is this does not give us convergence in a single $\alpha$ limit, and I'm not aware of any theorems that might help.  I've tried playing around with the inner product representation of the SOT convergence of $A_\alpha^*$ and $B_\alpha$, but so far to no avail.  Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: We have $$\langle A_\alpha B_\alpha x,y\rangle=\langle B_\alpha x,A_\alpha^* y\rangle.$$Since $B_\alpha$ and $A_\alpha^*$ converge SOT to $B$ and $A^*$, and the inner product is [jointly continuous (in two variables)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171487/inner-product-is-jointly-continuous) then...

Comment: Inner product jointly continuous, that's what I was missing.  Thank you very much!